# How to make Provider Hosted app available in another site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a Provider Hosted App in my Developer Site Collection.
How can I make it available as app and web parts in another site colleciont?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy the app to app catalog on central administration site.

Another options is to use **appregnew.aspx**, then use same AppID as ClientID as the web app has, then upload the app to the Site Collection.

If you want to insert the app into a page (insert app part) you need to use [Client Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481208%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: How about just using `appregnew.aspx`, use same AppID as ClientID as the web app has, then just upload the app to the Site Collection? We use this on one of our sites and it does seem to work

Comment: @eirikb that's a nice idea.

Comment: Provisioning it in the app catalog will not add a new instance to every site, it will provision one instance, and create links to it

Comment: Hello Nadeem Yousuf I would like first to use an app from the catalog as you suggested. Now the app is in a catalog in the same web application of my site collection. Still, I don't see it. Should I do anything else?Thanks

Comment: Hello @eirikb I've tried your idea. The app is uploaded in the site collection but I don't see it among the apps I can insert in a page.Maybe it is not possible to insert Porivder Hosted app on a site page? Sorry for the question but I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: When you say "insert into page", are you actually looking for "Client Web Part"? The app itself will just be a link to the web application of your provider hosted app

Comment: When I wrote insert into the page, I meant from the ribbon, modify page and add part or add web part. I thought I could add it from there into my page. Or maybe it's not possible? I don't see any Client Web PArt in the Ribbon by the way.

Comment: Ok @eirikb I see I hadn't created a ClientWebPart.Thanks now it's fine.